# How to flushdb in Redis with a smooth way?

Tags: redis

I use redis "flushdb" to flush all data in Redis but caused redis-server went away, I wondered the problem cound be cleaning a large amount of keys. So is there any idea for flushing Redis in a smoothly way? Maybe with more time for flushing all data?

Comment: What do you mean by "went away"?

Comment: redis server down, php always caused a error with "redis server went away"

Answer (score 1):

flushall is "delete all keys" as described here: http://redis.io/commands/flushall

Delete operations are blocking operations.
Large delete operations may block redis 1minute or more. (e.g. you delete a 16GB hash with tons of keys)

You should write a Script which uses cursors to do this.

//edit:
I found my old answer here and wanted to be more specific providing resources:

- Large number of keys, use [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan) to iterate over them with a cursor and do a gracefully cleanup in smaller batches.
- Large hash, use either [UNLINK](https://redis.io/commands/unlink) command to async delete or [HSCAN](https://redis.io/commands/hscan) to iterate over it with a cursor and do a gracefully cleanup.